# IAutoMappingOverride.Override not being called

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I can't seem to get the FluentNHibernate overrides to run. Here's my configuration method

```
private static void Configure()
{
    if (_configuration != null) return;

    _configuration = new Configuration();
    _configuration.Configure();
    _configuration
        .AddAssembly(typeof(IFoo).Assembly)
        .AddAssembly(OtherDataAssembly);
    var autoPersistenceModel = AutoMap
        .AssemblyOf<IFoo>()
        .AddEntityAssembly(OtherDataAssembly)
        .Conventions.AddAssembly(OtherDataAssembly)
        .Conventions.Add(DefaultCascade.None())
        .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<IFoo>()
        .UseOverridesFromAssembly(OtherDataAssembly)
        .OverrideAll(map => map.IgnoreProperty("IsIgnored"))
        .Where(IsTypeMatch);
    _sessionFactory = Fluently
        .Configure(Configuration)
        .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings
            .Add(autoPersistenceModel))
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

Here's my override class

```
public class FooOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<IFoo>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<IFoo> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Not.LazyLoad();
        mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Bar).Table("FooBar");
    }
}
```

Breakpoints I put in the `Override()` method are never hit when debugging, even when restarting IIS. How do I get this to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overrides are only run on the exact same class, not classes which are assignable to the class in the generic type parameter of `IAutoMappingOverride`.

Update:

The only other options i can think of now are:

- let FooOverride implement several IAuotMappingOverride<> for each class implementing IFoo
- add the overides yourself using Reflection. untestet:

  ```
  var overrideMethod = typeof(AutoPersistenceModel).GetMethod("Override");

  foreach (var type in typeof(IFoo).Assembly)
  {
      if (typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(type))
      {
          overrideMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(new Action<IFoo>(m => m.HasMayToMany(...)));
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Is there any alternative solution??